# An error that says that sayError: Parse error on line 1: {: asset_ids => ['AGH -^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got ':' has occurred

Tags: json

How can I fix it? Even though I endeavored to work out this problem, I couldn't find where is wrong.

```
                                { 
                                  : asset_ids => ["AGHhobo7pVQN5fZWqv3rhdc324ryT7qVTB"],
                                  : name_short => "A",
                                  : name => "A",
                                  : contract_url => "h",
                                  : issuer => "Ryu Nishida",
                                  : description => "h",
                                  : description_mime => "h",
                                  : type => "currency",
                                  : divisibility => 2,
                                  : link_to_website => "link_to_website",
                                  : icon_url => "icon_url",
                                  : image_url => "image_url2",
                                  : version => "version"
                                }
```

Comment: Yeah... that's not JSON...

Comment: Oh so you mean I need to make this json?

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten to make that one json with program

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what you're trying to do with it. You tagged your question as JSON and provide zero context, so impossible for me or anyone else to tell you what needs to be done.

Comment: I tried to write a JSON file which is related to Bitcoin, also the file is needed to be accessable.
Therefore, I had to upload the file to gist with a  program.

Comment: Thanks anyway.
ありがとうございました。